# What algorithm does VSCode use to achieve highlighting in search results

Tags: algorithm, visual-studio-code, search, fuzzy-search

For example, searching for "test" returns "**Te**rminal: **S**plit **T**erminal" as one of the results, with "Te", "S", and "T" being highlighted. How is this achieved? As far as I'm aware, regular fuzzy search (based on Levenshtein distance) will only provide you with distances between strings.

[image: Example of a search]

I've been looking up different approximate string matching algorithms, and  wasn't able to find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use VSCode but based on the screenshot I would guess that it combines results from substring matching and from some kind of "word initial matching", where it matches if you can split the search string (for instance "Test" into "te", "s", "t"), and each of the parts is at the beginning of a word (and in the same order).

Comment: It's clearly not based on Levenshtein distance in any case, as the longer strings would be much further down than any other much shorter string, so it would be completely useless.